# Best way to update database on missing lines

Tags: mysql, database

I pull in a dataset from an external party into my own database. The number lines on this set can change (added/removed). So on each import there needs to be a check on the lines that needs to be removed. I was wondering what the best solution for this was.

```
Dataset day 1
Id|value
1|abc
2|cbd
3|xyz

Dataset day 2
Id|value
1|abc
3|Fhg
```

On the ID 1&3 I can simply run an `insert on duplicate key update` query.
On ID 2 I don’t have any information on day 2.

So the approaches I’m currently looking at and need your help on what the best/preferred solution is:

1. Delete full dataset from the table and then import full dataset again on new import
2. Add an `updateDateTime` field, which is automatically filled by the update trigger. Run afterwards a second query that deletes all rows that haven’t been updates
3. Store all ID’s in an array/table which can be used to match to the new dataset. The left over ID’s can be used to remove from the database
4. Other.....

What are your preferences and/or idea’s?

Comment: At some point someone is going to ask a 'what happened to?' question. If you don't have the data then that's going to be tricky to answer, I know you may still have the received datasets but you would still have to load and audit trail them to answer. So I would think about maintaining an an inserted/amended date and an audit table for inserts/updates and move the deletes to the audit log as a daily batch job. BUT I may be overthinking it and really only you can say what is most appropriate,

Comment: 4. You could have a 'deleted' date type column. Every day you could use a transaction to update the entire dataset, setting deleted to today's date where deleted is null. Then you execute your INSERT/UPDATE , setting deleted back to null for all found rows, and close the transaction.

Comment: Thanks both. The solution of @Strawberry does the trick! P.Salmon great suggestion! Although a little overkill for the current ask. Will keep it in mind for a future solution if needed.